# Google Glass default Immersion project doesn't work

Tags: android, android-activity, google-glass

I'm trying to fiddle with Google Glass for a project of mine. And when I created a new Immersion project, it cannot find any default Activity. And when I looked at the manifest, it doesn't have the usual `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />` and  `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />` in it so I added them. It can be played on the Glass now but it just showed another screen (or it's called a Card maybe? I'm still new in this.) and it just got dismissed automatically. Why did this happen? How do I fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Just logcatted it. It shows this error:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.glass.widget.CardBuilder`

Comment: additional info: the Glass is already on XE20.1 and says it's up to date. I've got the Wifi on and I don't know how to update it because it doesn't show any new update.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. I'll downgrade my GDK. But I don't know how actually. Anyway, I'll close this question and just try to find how to downgrade.